# Javascript/jQuery Load function, text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, text, selection

I have a console on my website which shows a log file, and i've set it up so it refreshes every 500 ms.

```
jQuery(document).bind("ready", function() {
$("#console").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
    function doStuff() {
        $( "#console" ).load("console/getlog.php");
        $('#console').scrollTop($('#console')[0].scrollHeight);

    } 
setInterval(doStuff, 500);
});
```

that works fine, but the problem arrives when i try to select some text in the console. Every time it updates, my selection is cancelled

what can i do to solve this?

Comment: Pause the refresh when you click it, or when it gets focused.

Comment: A quick note, that `load` function is firing every half second regardless of the status of the last one. It may be better to use a `setTimeout` inside the callback of the previous `load` request based on the success/failure. Else, if something go awry with the server, you have a bad request going out every half second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like MelanciaUK suggested, pause the `doStuff()` when the console is in focus.

You may detect that focus via mouseover/mouseout (so the console stops updating when you hover it), or on mousedown/mouseup, which isn't that usable since you have hardly time to press Cmd + C to save your selection.

Some dirty example:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZEW5s/ (updated with pause after mouseup: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEW5s/1/)

tymeJV suggestion to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` is a good one, though.

Comment: is it possible to pause it for about 5-10 seconds when the user starts selection, that would give them plenty of time to select and copy. I just imagine the situation when someone has their mouse hovering without knowing

Comment: That's definitely possible. I updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZEW5s/1/ - removed the hover stuff and added some _focusTimer which prevents the doStuff() function from running after `mouseup` for `_focusTimer.threshold` miliseconds. Also added `.pause` class to the element to indicate that the update function is paused.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$( "#console" ).load("console/getlog.php");` to update your console, consider using `$( "#console" ).append();`.  This should prevent the whole thing from reloading and removing your selection.

You can do something like `append(getLog());` where `getLog()` is a function that returns the content of the log.  Append can be used with hard coded content (text/html) or the results from a function.

[More information on .append() here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp)

[Also here - jQuery API doc](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: append just keeps printing the same over and over again

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of solving it is by making the delay long so you got time to select the text.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer, but I can't comment, so here it goes.
There are some methods for accessing and manipulating the selection, although they depend on the browser if I remember correctly. Check this out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

I'd recommend changing the doStuff() to save the current selection, and try to apply it after the loading.